# Tab extract extension on Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there a similar extension on Firefox that lets you extract all tabs with certain URL to a new window like [Tab Extract](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-extract/iphchnegaodmijmkdlbhbanjhfphhikp) for Chrome?

Comment: Have you searched them on Firefox's extension store?

Comment: @BagasSanjaya yes, hence this question. Did you find it?